# Cannot cast argument of arrow function as an interface?

Tags: javascript, angular, function, typescript, casting

My code looks like this:

```
interface ImyInterface {
    v: number;
}

class A implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit() {
       let myObservable$ = getObs();
       myObservable$.subscribe(data => {
           const foo = data as ImyInterface;
           foo. // <-- VS Code IDE autcompletes with 'v'
       });
   }
};
```

However, I thought that declaring an extra variable is a tiny overhead, so I tried dong this instead:

```
myObservable$.subscribe(data => {
     data = data as ImyInterface;
     data. // <-- VS Code IDE didn't autocomplete
});
```

Why this approach fails? I am thinking that it has to do with variable scoping, and maybe shadowing? I do not know, since I am a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to do it that way:

```
myObservable$.subscribe((data: ImyInterface) => {
    alert(data.v);
});
```

Using the code above you are declaring that your subscribe function expect an argument that is implementing `ImyInterface` interface.

Comment: Good. But why my approach failed? Thanks for the upvote =)